# Force to update a field even if didnt change in a entity that use dynamicupdate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a requirement to always update a field of a entity when this entity is updating. My entity is like:

```
@Table(name = "Car")
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
public class CarEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "uuid2"
    )
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "Client_Id")
    private String clientId;

    @Column(name = "Color", length = 45)
    private String color;
    
    @Column(name = "Brand")
    private String brand;
}

public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, String>{
}
```

Clientid has always to be force to update when any other field is updating like brand or color. The reason of this is that in my db I have to have a register that the update need to be log with the user. But when JPA does it because the DynamicUpdate, only build the update with the fields that are different from before but I want to build it always with the user on it.

I didn't find any tip of what I can do, when I do

```
// things before
car.setColor("red");
car.setUser("me");
car.saveAndFlush(car)

// do more things
car.setColor("blue");
car.saveAndFlush(car)
```

So when I go with this code to the db I see:

```
update color, user
update color
```

Any idea of what I can do to always pass the user?
Thanks!

Comment: Add a check in saveandflush is user is set if not then throw an error or don't update it. depneding on your use case

Comment: The thing is that when jpa do the update I want always to put user (even if it is the same one as before)

Comment: are you clearing the user somewhere  ?? if not then it should be in memory from the first saveAndFlush.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to contribute to hibernate.  Possibly add an optional attribute to `@DynamicUpdate` to always include the designated entity field(s) in the general SQL.  Or maybe  create a new annotation, something like `@AlwaysUpdate` applied to an entity field, to modify the default behavior of `@DynamicUpdate`.  But what if no other field value actually changed?

Comment: @StackFlowed, no necesarially need to be clearing the user. There is 2 updates with the same user.

Comment: @AndrewS I will contact the hibernate to see how we can do it. And for your question, if only the user change, for my understand is the row has to change ( the owner sell the car and now other person has it).

Comment: @David_Garcia instead of clearing after saveAndFlush check before if there is no user then dont clear it if there is a user passed then clear the old value.